# SQL Join where Columns equal Value(s)

Tags: sql

I've only done some codecademy with SQL (i.e. super new to this), but I'm using it within an application and having trouble figuring out how it translates.

I'm trying to do a join where [1].DEPCD equals [2].DEPCD, but I want it to view 'DEPCD's 100 and 200 as interchangeable.

This code works for part of it:

```
[1].EMPLID=[2].EMPLID AND 
[1].DEPCD in ('100', '200') AND [2].DEPCD in ('100', '200')
```

and this works for the other part of it:

```
[1].EMPLID=[2].EMPLID AND 
[1].DEPCD = [2].DEPCD
```

Come to think of it as I'm typing this, I can maybe(?) do:

```
[1].EMPLID=[2].EMPLID AND 
(([1].DEPCD in ('100', '200') AND [2].DEPCD in ('100', '200')) OR
([1].DEPCD not in ('100', '200') AND [2].DEPCD not in ('100', '200')) AND
[1].DEPCD = [2].DEPCD)
```

It accepts the syntax, but that just seems sloppy.  What is a clean way?

Table examples

```
[1]
EMPLD | DEPCD | NAME
101   | 100   | Todd
101   | 200   | Todd
101   | 300   | Todd

[2]
EMPLD | DEPCD | AMOUNT
101   | 100   | 25
101   | 200   | 35
101   | 300   | 50
```

Report example:

```
EMPLD | DESCRIPTION | NAME | AMOUNT
101   | 100 + 200   | Todd | 60
101   | 300         | Todd | 50
```

The description column is from a field I created where I combined 100 and 200.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: I updated it with samples.  The syntax I posted works, but there must be a cleaner way to code it.

Comment: Your syntax should still work if you remove the `not in` part: `[1].EMPLID=[2].EMPLID AND 
(([1].DEPCD in ('100', '200') AND [2].DEPCD in ('100', '200')) OR
[1].DEPCD = [2].DEPCD)`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not 100% sure how your entire query looks, given your sample data and expected results, here's one option using `aggregation` with `case`:

```
select t1.empld, 
    t1.name, 
    case when t1.depcd in (100,200) then '100 + 200' 
         else cast(t1.depcd as varchar(100)) 
    end as description,
    sum(t2.amount) as amount
from t1 
    join t2 on t1.empld = t2.empld and t1.depcd = t2.depcd
group by t1.empld, 
    t1.name, 
    case when t1.depcd in (100,200) then '100 + 200' 
         else cast(t1.depcd as varchar(100)) 
    end
```

- [Online Demo](https://rextester.com/LWJ36194)